# Rails : export to excel all that users are visible in the current page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a Rails Project and I have the next issue :

I am have the users view, where is all users are listed and on click on every user i redirect to the view with all information about the clicked users, that's what i want to do is , to export all the users which is visible in that view to excel file with all the information about them.

So the columns will be something like this :

|id|name|notes|balance|
|1|user1|aasfs|33.44  |
|2|user2|aasfs|33.44  |
|3|user3|aasfs|33.44  |

I almost have done the logic for exporting the data on the controller :

users controller:

```
def index
    @users = User.all.page(params[:page]).order('created_at DESC').per(10)
    if params[:search]
      @users = Client.search(params[:search]).page(params[:page]).order('created_at DESC').per(10)
    end
  end

def export_to_csv
    @users = User.find(:all)
    csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << ["Id", "name","notes","balance"]
      @clients.each do |user|
        csv << [user.id, user.name, user.notes, user.balance ]
      end
    end

    send_data csv_string,
              :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
              :disposition => "attachment; filename=users.csv"
  end
```

I know that i need to implement an if statement too, to export only the users with the same ID , but my proble is in the front end part:

```
    <%= link_to '#', { onclick: "$('#export_users').submit()", class:"btn btn-primary" } do %>
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> <span class="bold">Export</span>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to '#', { onclick: "$('#delete_users').submit()", class:"btn btn-danger" } do %>
       <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> <span class="bold">Delete</span>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mrg-top-20">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="hpanel">
      <div class="panel-heading hbuilt">
          users
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="wdt-30"></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <%= form_tag(delete_users_path, method: :post,:id => 'delete_users',) do %>
              <% @clients.each do |client| %>
                <tr>
                  <td class="wdt-30"><%= check_box_tag 'ids[]', client.id, false, :class => 'table-row-checkbox' %></td>
                  <td><%= link_to client.name, edit_client_path(client)  %></td>
                   <td></td>
                </tr>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
          </table>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How i can get and all the users ID's which is shown in the page (example we can have 30 users per page) and send request to the controller to export the users?

i am havin a form where i delete checked users, so i cant implement form in another form , so which is the best solution ? maybe to get the users ID with javascript ?

p.s sorry for my bad english, it is not my native language.

Comment: Could you post controller responsible for displaying users on the page?

Comment: Hey, You have the form already no need to create the new or other forms, Instead of it you can send the action name for doing operation, like export or delete.
It's not a good way to read all the ID's via JavaScript, You can submit the form, that will submit all the ID's which are selected on the form.

Comment: Yes but i want to get all the id's which is shown on the page, and not only the selected ones. Thank you

Comment: Then why you have added the check-box in your form ? Can you please tell me the reason.

Comment: the check-box is added for the delete functionality!

Answer (score 0):

As you already have pagination in the `index` action, it is easiest to reuse the same logic, but output CSV instead of HTML.

You didn't specify Your Rails version, but with any recent version the fastest way to achieve this is using Rails's `respond_to` helper.

In your HTML create a link back to current page, but with different format:

```
<%= link_to "Download CSV", params.merge(:format => :csv) %>
```

And then modify the controller:

```
def index
  @users = User.all.page(params[:page]).order('created_at DESC').per(10)
  if params[:search]
    @users =   Client.search(params[:search]).page(params[:page]).order('created_at DESC').per(10)
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # renders HTML view
    format.csv do 
      send_data users_to_csv(@users),
              :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
              :disposition => "attachment; filename=users.csv"
    end
  end
end

def users_to_csv(users)
  CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << ["Id", "name","notes","balance"]
    users.each do |user|
      csv << [user.id, user.name, user.notes, user.balance ]
    end
  end
end
```

This way, what ever pagination settings or searche you use, exactly the same set of users will be exported as CSV.

Note: I renamed the `export_to_csv` and made it return CSV string instead, so it would be more uniform which are helper methods and which are actual outputting actions.